# CPLEX: How can you take the maximum/minimimum of an array?

Tags: arrays, max, min, cplex, opl

I calculated costs for a lot of scenarios and decisions. I would like to take the maximum over all the scenarios per decision. Afterwards, I would like to take the minimum of all these maximums per decision. CPLEX returns this error: "*unexpected ')', expecting in*   ". Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
minimize t;
 
subject to{

m[d] == max(c[d,1..nbscenarios]);  
t== min (m[1..nbdecisions]);

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me help with the syntax

```
range r=1..4;
int nbscenarios=5;
range s=1..nbscenarios;

dvar int c[r][s];
dvar int m[r];
dvar int t; 
minimize t;

subject to{

forall(d in r )m[d] == max(i in s)c[d][i];
t== min (d in r)(m[d]);
 }
```

works fine